# How to populate unchecked checkboxes for edit page in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I have an edit page of a recipe that is populated correctly using findOne axios call and populates all of the information for that recipe. However, it only displays the checkboxes that are checked and not the checkbox objects that are unchecked. I want it to display all checkboxes, both checked and unchecked. See below code.

Edit.jsx

```
const Edit = (props) => {

    const { _id } = useParams({})
    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        title: "",
        description: "",
        tags: [
            { name: "Athletic/Higher caloric", isChecked: false },
            { name: "Aggressive Weight Loss", isChecked: false },
            { name: "Kid-Friendly", isChecked: false },
            { name: "Non-Vegan", isChecked: false },
            { name: "Diabetes reversal", isChecked: false },
            { name: "Quick and Easy", isChecked: false },
        ],
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/recipes/${_id}`)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data.results);
                setForm(res.data.results);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                setErrors(err)
            })
    }, [_id])
```

My checkedHandler from create page:

```
const handleCheckedTags = (index) => {
        setForm(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            tags: [
                ...prev?.tags?.map(
                    ({ isChecked, ...rest }, idx) => (
                        idx === index ?
                            { ...rest, isChecked: !isChecked } :
                            { ...rest, isChecked })
                )]
        }));
    }
```

And here is my return code (the edit form):

```
return (
  <form>
       {
        form.tags.map((tag, i) => (
          <div className="form-inline mx-3" key={i}>
              <input
                   type="checkbox"
                   value={tag.name}
                   checked={tag.isChecked}
                   onChange={(event) => handleCheckedTags(i)}
                   key={i}
                 />
             </div>
           ))}
   </div>
   <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

I know I have a single form state to begin with, which was how I setup my create form. Should I have set it up differently or is there a way to make sure the unchecked checkboxes display for the edit page?

Thanks in advance for your help.

### **Update**

With some help I was able to merge the results from the server (with the recipe info in it) into the original form by using map operators. See below.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = "NutritarianEats - Edit"
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/recipes/${_id}`)
            .then(res => {

                const updatedTags = [...form.tags];
                const result = res.data.results;

                result.tags.map((tag, i) => {
                    updatedTags.map((existingTag) => {
                        if (existingTag.name === tag.name) {
                            existingTag.isChecked = tag.isChecked
                        }
                    })
                })
                setForm({ ...result, tags: updatedTags });

            })
            .catch(err => {
                setErrors(err)
            })
    }, [_id])
```

I think I could have not made the tags an array initially setting up my model and instead made it one object. Something I need to work on, but this code worked for me.

Comment: First, What type/kind of data you are receiving from the request?  Second, You set the initial state for form. But you override the state when you the request is resolved ` setForm(res.data.results);`.

Comment: I'm receiving all the information I needed (title, descrip., tags, etc.) in one object when i console.log (res.data.results). The tags object shows up on the page of just that one checked item, and not the other 5 options. Is there another way I should set the form state so that the other options show up?

Comment: Do you want to merge the data received from response into existing form state? Currently you set the initial state in form & you override the that state value when you received the response.

Comment: Yes, I want to merge the data received from response into a new form state.So if the user wants, they can add new tags in addition to the old tags.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-sunset-ln779e?file=/src/App.js
Please check its working fine. Please check the useEffect code where i set the data. May be you are making some mistake in merging the response data & current state.

Comment: I was making a mistake with the merging in that I wasn't making a copy of the form and updating it with the new information, but I got the answer. The issue was that my results from the server only produced two checked objects so I changed it to loop through the old form and match it to the results by name. I can update it in my question.

Comment: Thank you for your help Nouman. It clarified how I wasn't setting state correctly and needed to override my original form. Also, my apologies, I explained incorrectly about new tags. I meant new checked items within the existing choices. So if the recipe was tagged 'Kid-Friendly', but the user wanted to add 'Quick & Easy', they could do that in the form, so the recipe would be updated to have 'Kid-Friendly' and 'Quick & easy'. So I added special logic for the tags. Having the tags key values as an array was probably not ideal.

Comment: I saw your updated code. If your tags have unique name then it think you can use object instead of array with name as key and boolean as value. You apply map two which doesn't seem a good way. It will be easier if you use object. But you can stick to that method that suits you. Happy Coding @ 
Jennifer Ehala